# Proof that a sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence, let $\; 0 < q < 1$ such that
$\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$  $\;n>2$

$ \left | a_{n+1} -a_n \right | < q\left | a_{n} -a_{n-1}\right |$

prove that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.

Well, I thought about proving it this way:

$ \left | a_{n+1} -a_n \right | < q*\left | a_{n} -a_{n-1}\right |<\left | a_{n} -a_{n-1}\right | $

therefore $ \left | a_{n+1} -a_n \right | <\left | a_{n} -a_{n-1}\right | \;$  for each $n>2$ and that obviously shows us that the sequence converges because the gaps between each $2$ indexes reduces as $n$ grows.

I have a feeling however that this is not a formal way of proving this, it seems too easy.

Comment: What is the metric space? Do you know $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs? And you are right, decreasing difference of terms is not sufficient. Consider the sequence $a_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1/i)$, which is known to be divergent. Also, your proof doesn't use $q$, which should concern you.

Comment: @TheCount the metric space is $\mathbb{R}$ and I don't really know $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs, only $\varepsilon$ proofs (sequences, not functions). I also recently studied Cauchy sequences which seems to relate. How would you recommend approaching this?

Comment: The current answer is good. I might post another, written more formally.

Answer (score 4):

$|a_{n+1} - a_n| < |a_n - a_{n-1}|$ is not sufficient to prove convergence of $(a_n)$. A counterexample is $a_n := 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$.

---

For any $n$,
$$|a_{n+1} - a_n| < q |a_n - a_{n-1}| < q^2 |a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}| < \cdots < q^{n-1} |a_2 - a_1|.$$
Use this to show $(a_n)$ is Cauchy (and therefore convergent).

> For $m < n$ we have $$|a_n - a_m| \le \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |a_{k+1} - a_k| \le |a_2 - a_1| \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} q^{k-1} \le |a_2 - a_1| \frac{q^{m-1}}{1-q}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response.

2 questions about this: 

1: How can you assume $|a_n - a_{n-1}| < q^2 |a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}|$

2: Isn't problematic "reversing" to $|a_2 - a_{1}| $ ? because your assumingly might be dealing with a finite amount of indexes.

Comment: Your idea and my idea are the same, and you typed yours first, but I didn't want all my typing to go to waste. Ha. +1 for succinctness, in particular!

Comment: @vpam I am only assuming $|a_n - a_{n-1} | < q | a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}|$. Multiplying both sides by $q$ yields $q |a_n - a_{n-1}| < q^2 |a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}|$.

Comment: @vpam For any given $n$, it is possible to make the chain of inequalities lead all the way from $|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ to $|a_2 - a_1|$. It is finite because $n$ is finite.

Answer (score 3):

Choose an integer $m<n$. By the triangle inequality,

$$|a_n-a_m|\leq |a_n-a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-1}-a_m|.$$

You can continue to apply the triangle inequality in this way until you obtain:

$$|a_n-a_m|\leq |a_n-a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|+|a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}|+\cdots+|a_{m+1}-a_m|$$

And then from the problem statement, this is strictly less than:

$$q^{n}|a_2-a_1|+q^{n-1}|a_2-a_1|+\cdots+|q^{m-1}|a_2-a_1|=|a_2-a_1|(q^n+q^{n-1}+\cdots+q^m-1).$$

So, choosing a large enough $m$ (and hence $n$) will guarantee the distance between *any* terms beyond a certain point will be arbitrarily small, so the sequence is Cauchy. If you are in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with the usual metric, which you probably are, then your metric space is complete, and therefore convergence is implied.

EDIT: Your only mistake, and it is common, is that you must prove that after a certain integer, *every* pair $(a_n,a_m)$ has arbitrarily small distance, not just pairs of successive terms. I have made that mistake so many times.